# why the change is in place for the list with elisp?

Tags: list, emacs, elisp, cdr

I have a question about elisp. For example:

```
(setq trees '(maple oak pine birch))
      -> (maple oak pine birch)
(setcdr (nthcdr 2 trees) nil)
      -> nil
trees
      -> (maple oak pine)
```

I thought `(nthcdr 2 trees)` returns a new list - `(pine birch)` and put the list into the `setcdr` expression, which should not change the value of `trees`. Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation string for `nthcdr`, you'll see that it just returns a pointer to the "nth" "cdr" - which is a pointer into the original list.  So you're modifying the original list.

Doc string:

```
Take cdr N times on LIST, return the result.
```

*Edit* Wow, "pointer" seems to stir up confusion.  Yes, Lisp has pointers.

Just look at the box diagrams used to explain list structure in lisp (here's [Emacs's documentation on that very thing](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Box-Diagrams.html)):

```
     --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
    |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
     --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
      |            |            |
      |            |            |
       --> rose     --> violet   --> buttercup
```

Look at all those arrows, they almost look like they're .... pointing to things.  When you take the `cdr` of a list, you get what the 2nd box refers to (aka "points" to), be it an atom, a string, or another cons cell.  Heck, check it out on Wikipedia's entry for [CAR and CDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR).

If it feels better to call it a reference, use that terminology.

`cdr` certainly does **NOT** return a **copy** of what it refers to, which is what was confusing [RNAer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489564/rnaer).

Comment: Would you mind to point out the doc where it says *nthcdr* returns a *pointer* to the nth cdr?

Comment: There is no such thing as a *pointer* in Lisp. However, `cdr` and `nthcdr` returns a *cons-cell* (which is what lists are built of), it is the *same* const cell which originally was part of the list. If you destructively modify it, that change will be reflected in the original list.

Comment: @Lindydancer Sure, you don't have raw pointers, but saying that you return a cons cell often evokes images of a *copy* of something.  And in reality, you're getting the pointer - just like the box diagrams show, it's really not that scary.

Comment: @ring0 What is the value of the `cdr` of a cons cell?  It's a pointer (aka reference to the next element in the list).  Look at the box diagrams, that's exactly what is drawn.

Comment: The reason why I objected is that whenever one start talking about *pointers*, the next question is always "so, how to I take the *address of* something". Well, in lisp, you can't...

Answer (score 3):

*R:  "Look, in the sky! The Lambda Signal! A citizen is in trouble Lambda Man!"*

*LM: "I see it! And I've got just the box art they need."*

---

In Lisps, lists are singly-linked data structures, comprised of elements called *cons cells*. Each of these cells is a structure that consists of

1. a pointer to a value
2. a pointer to the next cell

These are called the *car* and *cdr* respectively for historical reasons. Here's the traditional box art representing a 3-element list:

```
Structure:    (car . cdr -)--->(car . cdr -)--->(car . cdr)
                |                |                |      |
                v                v                v      v
Values:         1                2                3     nil
```

The `car` and `cdr` functions allow you to work with lists from this low level of abstraction, and return the values of the respective cells. Thus, `car` returns the 'value' of the cell, and `cdr` dereferences to the remainder of the list. `nthcdr` is a generalisation on top of `cdr` for convenience.

The value returned by `cdr` is a reference to a raw data structure, which is mutable at this level. If you change the value of a cons-cell's cdr, you are changing the underlying structure of the list.

Given:

```
 let A = '(1 2)    ~= (1 . -)-->(2 . nil)

 let B = '(3 4)    ~= (3 . -)-->(4 . nil)
```

Setting the cdr of `(cdr A)` to B will destructively concatenate A and B such that A is now the structure below:

```
 A                   B     
 (1 . -)-->(2 . -)-->(3 . -)-->(4 . nil)
```

As we've shown, a `nil` value in a cell's cdr represents the end of the list - there's nothing more that can be traversed. If we set the cdr of A to `nil`, we lobotomise the list, such that A is now

```
A                  
(1 . nil)  <- [Not pointing to anything - the rest of the list shall go wanting]
```

This is pretty much what you've done - you've mutated the underlying data structures using low-level functions. :) By setting one of the cell's cdrs to `nil`, you've trimmed the end off your list.

Comment: One rule of thumb is that functions containing `car` or `cdr` in their name are often lower-level and destructive in elisp.

Answer (score 0):

This is called 'mutation'. And is present everywhere apart from Haskell.

There are functions that mutate the data structures and functions that duplicate it.